# Finding the combination of strings that occurs the most in given string

Tags: python

I have a combination of values that occur the most in given list of strings.

```
combination of values == value-value-value-value-value
```

So combination needs to have 5 values, and values can repeat.

```
all_values = ["CONJ", "NUM", "ADV", "PRT", "ADP", "PRON", "VERB", "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN"]


all_strings = ["DET-VERB-PRON-PRON-VERB-VERB-ADP",
"DET-NOUN-DET-NOUN-CONJ-PRON-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NUM-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADV-VERB-ADV-VERB",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-PRT-ADP-PRON-NOUN-DET-VERB-NUM-NOUN-ADP-ADV-VERB",
"NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-NUM-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-ADV-VERB-DET-NOUN-PRON-VERB-VERB-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADP-PRON-ADJ-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-PRT-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADP-DET-NOUN-DET-VERB-PRON-VERB-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADJ-VERB-ADV-VERB-ADJ-ADP-PRON-VERB-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-VERB",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-ADJ-PRON-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-NUM",
"NOUN-DET-NOUN-ADV-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"ADV-PRON-VERB-ADV-NUM-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-PRON-NOUN",
"ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-DET-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-PRT-VERB-DET-NOUN-PRT-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADJ-ADV-ADJ-ADV",
"PRON-NOUN-VERB-ADV-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"ADV-NOUN-VERB-ADV-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-DET-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-PRON",
"DET-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADP-PRON-VERB-PRON-NOUN-PRT-NOUN-CONJ-DET-NOUN-VERB-VERB",
"ADV-DET-ADJ-NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADJ-NUM-ADP-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRT-VERB-NOUN",
"ADV-ADP-PRON-VERB-ADP-ADV-VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"DET-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-ADJ-VERB-ADP-ADJ-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-VERB",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-PRON-ADP",
"PRON-VERB-DET-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-ADP-NOUN",
"DET-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-PRT-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-CONJ-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-VERB",
"ADP-NOUN-PRON-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN-NOUN-CONJ-ADJ-PRT-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-PRON-PRON-VERB-ADV-ADV",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-CONJ-PRON-VERB-VERB-ADP-DET",
"PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-CONJ-NOUN-CONJ-NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADP-VERB-PRON",
"NOUN-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADP-DET",
"DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-ADP-NUM-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-VERB-PRT-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"CONJ-DET-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"ADV-PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-PRT-VERB-PRON-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-PRT-VERB-VERB",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-ADJ",
"ADV-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"ADV-ADP-VERB-ADV-PRON-VERB-VERB",
"NOUN-DET-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADP-NUM-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-ADV-VERB-DET-VERB-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-ADV-ADJ-ADV-ADJ-ADP-DET",
"NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADJ-VERB-ADV",
"VERB-PRT-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADV-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NUM-NUM",
"PRON-ADV-VERB-NUM-NOUN-ADV-ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADV-NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-VERB-DET-ADV-ADJ-NOUN",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRON-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADV",
"ADV-VERB-PRT-NUM-NOUN-NOUN-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-ADV-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-ADJ-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADJ-VERB-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON-ADV",
"NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADP-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRON-PRT-VERB-NOUN"]
```

So I need to find if the best combination is for example `VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP` or `VERB-PRON-NOUN-ADV-VERB` or any other.

I was thinking of finding all possible combinations of values from `all_values` list, but I'm sure that there is a faster way.
Ofc, full `all_strings` has more than 50k values.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Assuming optional values are a,b,c,d,e, and strings are abcdeb,bcdebb,aaaaa, is bcdeb considered best, since it occurs twice whereas any other combination occurs once or not at all?

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: You obviously need to read each string, so the time complexity is at least linear, and on the other hand the straight-forward solution you've mentioned is also linear, so it sounds like you can't do any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick script that seems to do the job fairly quickly.

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import time

all_values = ["CONJ", "NUM", "ADV", "PRT", "ADP", "PRON", "VERB", "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN"]


all_strings = ["DET-VERB-PRON-PRON-VERB-VERB-ADP",
"DET-NOUN-DET-NOUN-CONJ-PRON-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NUM-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADV-VERB-ADV-VERB",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-PRT-ADP-PRON-NOUN-DET-VERB-NUM-NOUN-ADP-ADV-VERB",
"NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-NUM-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-ADV-VERB-DET-NOUN-PRON-VERB-VERB-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADP-PRON-ADJ-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-PRT-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADP-DET-NOUN-DET-VERB-PRON-VERB-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADJ-VERB-ADV-VERB-ADJ-ADP-PRON-VERB-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-VERB",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-ADJ-PRON-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-NUM",
"NOUN-DET-NOUN-ADV-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"ADV-PRON-VERB-ADV-NUM-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-PRON-NOUN",
"ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-DET-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-PRT-VERB-DET-NOUN-PRT-VERB-ADP-PRON-ADJ-ADV-ADJ-ADV",
"PRON-NOUN-VERB-ADV-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"ADV-NOUN-VERB-ADV-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-DET-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-PRON",
"DET-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADP-PRON-VERB-PRON-NOUN-PRT-NOUN-CONJ-DET-NOUN-VERB-VERB",
"ADV-DET-ADJ-NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADJ-NUM-ADP-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRT-VERB-NOUN",
"ADV-ADP-PRON-VERB-ADP-ADV-VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"DET-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-ADJ-VERB-ADP-ADJ-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-VERB",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-PRON-ADP",
"PRON-VERB-DET-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-ADP-NOUN",
"DET-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-PRT-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-CONJ-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-VERB-VERB",
"ADP-NOUN-PRON-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN-NOUN-CONJ-ADJ-PRT-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-PRON-PRON-VERB-ADV-ADV",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-CONJ-PRON-VERB-VERB-ADP-DET",
"PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-CONJ-NOUN-CONJ-NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADP-VERB-PRON",
"NOUN-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADP-DET",
"DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-ADP-NUM-ADJ-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-VERB-PRT-VERB-VERB-PRT-ADP-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"CONJ-DET-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"ADV-PRON-VERB-VERB-DET-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-PRT-VERB-PRON-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN-PRT-VERB-VERB",
"PRON-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-ADJ",
"ADV-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"ADV-ADP-VERB-ADV-PRON-VERB-VERB",
"NOUN-DET-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADP-NUM-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-NOUN",
"ADJ-NOUN-ADV-VERB-DET-VERB-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-ADV-ADJ-ADV-ADJ-ADP-DET",
"NOUN-PRON-VERB-ADJ-VERB-ADV",
"VERB-PRT-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-VERB-ADV-NOUN-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADV-ADJ-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-PRT-VERB-DET-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-DET-VERB-VERB-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NUM-NUM",
"PRON-ADV-VERB-NUM-NOUN-ADV-ADJ-ADP-PRON-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN-ADV-NOUN-VERB-VERB-PRON-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-VERB-ADP-PRON",
"NOUN-VERB-DET-ADV-ADJ-NOUN",
"NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRON-DET-NOUN-NOUN-ADV",
"ADV-VERB-PRT-NUM-NOUN-NOUN-PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-ADV-NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"VERB-PRON-VERB-DET-ADJ-ADP-PRON",
"PRON-VERB-ADJ-NOUN-ADP-NOUN",
"NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADJ-VERB-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-ADP-PRON-ADV",
"NOUN-NOUN-VERB-NOUN-VERB-ADV-ADP-DET-ADJ-NOUN",
"NOUN-VERB-VERB-NOUN-NOUN-NOUN-ADV-VERB-PRON-PRT-VERB-NOUN"]

start = time.time()

string_mat = [s.split('-') for s in all_strings]
freq = dd(int)
for row in string_mat:
    for i in range(len(row) - 4):
        freq[tuple(row[i:i+5])]+=1
max_freq,pattern = max((f,p) for p,f in freq.items())

print("Best pattern:",'-'.join(pattern))
print("frequency:",max_freq)
print("Computation time: {:.3} seconds".format(time.time()-start))
```

Result:

```
Best pattern: VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN
frequency: 4
Computation time: 0.00149 seconds
```

Bonus: to get a list of all patterns and their frequency in descending order, do the following (after the above script).

```
for f,p in sorted([(f,p) for (p,f) in freq.items()],reverse = True):
        print('-'.join(p),f': {f} time(s)')
```

Here are the top 5:

```
VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN : 4 time(s)
PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP : 4 time(s)
NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN : 4 time(s)
DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN : 4 time(s)
VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN : 3 time(s)
```

---

Implementation using the collections.Counter object:

```
start = time.time()
string_mat = [s.split('-') for s in all_strings]
freq = Counter([tuple(row[i:i+5]) for row in string_mat for i in range(len(row)-4)])

print('5 most common:')
for p,f in freq.most_common(5):
    print('{}: {}'.format('-'.join(p),f))
print("Computation time: {:.3} seconds".format(time.time()-start))
```

Result:

```
5 most common:
NOUN-VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN: 4
VERB-ADP-DET-NOUN-NOUN: 4
PRON-VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP: 4
DET-NOUN-ADP-DET-NOUN: 4
VERB-DET-NOUN-ADP-NOUN: 3
Computation time: 0.00294 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks, and one more question,  how can I find top 3 combinations?

Comment: Run the for loop that I added at the end, but change the top to `for f,p in sorted([(f,p) for (p,f) in freq.items()],reverse = True)[:3]:`

Comment: @Kelly You're right, sorry for not responding earlier. I've fixed the code; it seems that I had an off by one error and was ignoring the last "value" in each row.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Btw, I think `Counter` is more appropriate for counting, plus it already has its `most_common` method.

Comment: @KellyBundy ...I really need to get better about looking for existing answers instead of hacking stuff together. Thanks for the information